# Send objects via Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I am new to stocks in C#, I wish to send a Object in C#. Have been using BinaryWriter to send data (works fine for string), but it doesn't seem to have a method like

```
writer.Writer(new SerliaizedObject());
```

How do we achieve this using BinaryReader/BinaryWriter

**UPDATE:**
I used the following functions to convert by object to byte and send it across to the client

```
 public static byte[] SerializeToBytes<T>(T item)
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static object DeserializeFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
```

To send the data is used:

```
    formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    MessageBox.Show(SerializeToBytes<mydata>(new mydata()).Length+"");
    writer.Write(SerializeToBytes<mydata>(new mydata()));
    ChatBox.AppendText("Client Says :" + UserMessage.Text + "\r\n");
```

And to read the data I used:

```
   while (true)
   {
        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(120);
        mydata temp = DeserializeFromBytes(bytes) as mydata;
        ChatBox.AppendText("Server Says " + temp + "\r\n");
   }
```

But the reader doesn't seem to work, Any Ideas?

Comment: serialize the object to a byte array and write that?

Comment: You do not need to seek to the beginning of the stream before converting to array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter) to write serializable objects to streams in binary format:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(fs, mySerializable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the first 4 bytes as length header, and in the receive loop you add a variable bytesReadSoFar. Then you know when everything is received.